# How to resolve design.sv:1 : syntax error on the EDA playground for the sillyfunction taken from Digital Design And Computer Architecture?

Tags: system-verilog, test-bench

For understanding SystemVerilog, I have been writing the codes on the **Digital Design And the Computer Architecture**. So, I wrote the first example and the testbench in the book.

Design

```
module sillyfunction(input logic a,b,c,
                     output logic y);
  assign y = ~a & ~b & ~c |
            a & ~b & ~c |
            a & ~b & c;
endmodule
```

Testbench

```
module testbench();
  input a, b, c;
  output y; 
  sillyfunction dut(a,b,c,y);  
  initial begin
    $dumpfile("file.vcd");
    $dumpvars(1);
    a = 0; b = 0; c = 0;
    #10
    c = 1;
    #10
    b = 1; c = 0;
    #10
    c = 1;
    #10
    a = 1; b = 0; c = 0;
    #10
    c = 1;
    #10
    b = 1; c = 0;
    #10
    c = 1;
  end
endmodule
```

The problem is I have encountered the error:

```
[2021-10-30 14:44:15 EDT] iverilog '-Wall' design.sv testbench.sv  && unbuffer vvp a.out  
design.sv:1: syntax error
I give up.
Exit code expected: 0, received: 1
Done
```

I tried to debug it with the changing the input and output variables to `reg` and `wire` which has no effect. I also tried to

> $dumpvars(1) to $dumvars(0)

Which has no effects on the bug.

How can I resolve the bug?

Answer (score 1):

I also see that error when I run your code on an old version of `iverilog` on edaplayground.  I suspect the version you used only supports the old Verilog standard, but does not have much support for SystemVerilog features; hence, the vague syntax error message.  It probably did not recognize the `logic` keyword, which is specific to SystemVerilog.

You should switch to the latest version there (Icarus Verilog 0.10.0), which has better SystemVerilog support.  You will get a different message, but I didn't find that to be very helpful either.

But, switching to another simulator, like Cadence, produces a more helpful message:

```
  input a, b, c;
        |
xmvlog: *E,NOPORT (testbench.sv,10|8): input/output/inout 'a' not declared in port list [12.3.2(IEEE)].
```

Here is the link: [edaplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/BciV).

Typically, you don't need ports on a testbench since it is usually the top-level module.  Using `reg` and `wire`, as you mentioned is one way to fix the error.  Another way is to change:

```
  input a, b, c;
  output y;
```

to:

```
  logic a, b, c;
  logic y;
```

Answer (score 1):

Icarus Verilog (aka iverilog) version 0.9.* do not support SysmteVerilog. Version 0.10.* does support a limited subset of SystemVerilog features with the compiler flag `-g2012`. Note the **Compile Options** in the image from EDA playground

[image]

In your testbench, change:

```
input a, b, c;
output y;
```

to:

```
logic a, b, c; // could also be 'reg' type
wire y; // could also be 'logic' type
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the **port declaration style** you have followed for the module testbench.

This is a non-ANSI port declaration style and System-verilog discusses on this under the LRM standard section, **23.2.2.1 Non-ANSI style port declarations**. To get this working, you will have to change

```
module testbench(); -> module testbench(a,b,c,y);
```

Next, ports a,b,c and y are wires. A wire cannot be assigned like "a = 1;". So you can change a wire to a variable by :

```
input a, b, c; output y; -> input var a, b, c; output var y;
```

Comment: Testbenches typically do not have ports. `input a, b, c; output y;` should be `reg a, b, c; wire y;` and leave `module testbench();`. The error is on line 1 of design.sv, it has not yet parsed testbench.sv